# Using VBOs/IBOs in OpenGL ES 2.0 on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, vbo

I am trying to create a simple test program on android (API 10) using OpenGL ES 2.0 to draw a simple rectangle. I can get this to work with float buffers referencing the vertices directly, but i would rather do it with VBOs/IBOs. I have looked for countless hours trying to find a simple explanation (tutorial), but have yet to come across one. My code compiles and runs just fine, but nothing is showing up on the screen other than the clear color.

Here are some code chunks to help explain how I have it set up right now.

**Part of onSurfaceChanged():**

```
int[] buffers = new int[2];
GLES20.glGenBuffers(2, buffers, 0);
rectVerts = buffers[0];
rectInds = buffers[1];
GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, rectVerts);
GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (rectBuffer.limit()*4), rectBuffer, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, rectInds);
GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, (rectIndices.limit()*4), rectIndices, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

**Part of onDrawFrame():**

```
GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, rectVerts);
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, rectInds);
GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GLES20.GL_INT, 0);
```

Comment: Listing any books or simple tutorials would be quite helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see anything immediately wrong, but here's some ideas you can touch on.

1) 'Compiling and running fine' is a useless metric for an opengl program. Errors are reported through actively calling glGetError and checking compile and link status of the shaders with glGet(Shader|Program)iv. Do you check for errors anywhere?

2) You shouldn't be assuming that 0 is the correct index for vertices. It may work now but will likely break later if you change your shader. Get the correct index with glGetAttribLocation.

3) You're binding the verts buffer onDraw, but I don't see anything about the indices buffer. Is that always bound?

4) You could also try drawing your VBO with glDrawArrays to get the index buffer out of the equation, just to help debugging to see which part is wrong.

Otherwise what you have looks correct as far as I can tell in that small snippet. Maybe something else outside of it is going wrong.

Comment: 1. I am just getting started so I have not incorporated any opengl error checking yet. Just building from tutorials I have seen so far. But I will keep that in mind. 2. I have a handle to my vPosition (vertex shader) that I have been using interchangeably in those fields. Once again, this is what i got from others code that i wasn't sure the correct way. 3. It should be always bound from the onSurfaceChanged, but I am new so that might not be correct. 4. I just tried it with glDrawArray and it worked (but only drew one triangle since I only have 4 vertexes defined).

Comment: @Derek I just noticed in the spec for glDrawElements: "type: Specifies the type of the values in indices. Must be one of GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, or GL_UNSIGNED_INT."  Looks like GL_INT is an illegal argument to that function. If you had error checking you would have caught this :)

Comment: Yeah, I just saw that myself and changed it. That solved my problem. Thanks for the help Tim

Comment: BTW Tim - I did use the glGetError() to figure it out. I was getting a 1280 and looked at the spec to come to the same conclusion. So thanks again :)